# Foreign Keys in Fact Tables

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, olap-cube, dimensional-modeling

Is it more common to combine all the data into a fact table, such as:

```
-- MOVIE_SALE -- 
Year
Studio
Studio_CEO
Studio_Location
Studio_...
Movie_Name
Movie_Copyright
Movie_PrimaryLanguage
Amount
```

Or, is it more common and better practice to foreign key to other tables that contain the group of information, such as:

```
-- MOVIE_SALE -- 
Year
Studio_ID
Movie_ID
Amount
```

Why would one way be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (based on the tags you've added to your question) that you are asking about Kimball dimensional modelling, the first example you've given is not a valid fact table and the second one is. Therefore there is no question about which one might be preferred as the first example is not a candidate to be considered.

**UPDATE 1**

The long answer to your question as to why this wouldn't be a valid fact table (and I hope this doesn't come across as patronising as it is definitely not meant to be) is that you need to read a book on Dimensional modelling: [The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Definitive-Dimensional/dp/1118530802/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=ralph%20kimball&qid=1605520842&sr=8-1). Given that your question is about some very fundamental concepts of dimensional modelling, explaining how dimensional modelling works is too big a topic for this forum.

The short answer is that a fact table can, in most circumstances, only contain 2 types of column:

1. Foreign keys to the dimensions
2. Measures

Just for completeness, the 2 other types of column it could contain are:

1. Audit columns - anything you choose to add to track activity of a record
2. Degenerate dimensions: single attributes that don't have nay other related attributes that you would normally hold together in a dimension

Hope this helps?

Comment: could you please explain why the first one wouldn't be a valid fact table?

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to model the data as a star schema.

In your case the fact table is MovieSales. Your dimensions are date, studio,and movie.

Typically you will have more data in your fact tables so you would not want to keep repeating the metadata for each row.